# Having issues debugging website with VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web, windows-xp, debugging

I am attempting to debug a website on Windows XP. To be more specific, I am trying to debug an install of SiteFinity CMS. This CMS was installed via Microsoft's Web Platform Installer. It was installed to the default location of `C:\Inetput\wwwroot`.

The first error I got when attempting to debug the website with VS2008 was relatively straightforward and I solved it by changing the authentication of the web application in the IIS manager. Here is that error:

[image: Error 1]

The second error, the one that has me stumped, is not really an error message at all. When I go to debug the website now, I get an authentication prompt from `localhost:80`:

[image: Error 2]

I tried putting my windows user credentials in, but that did not work. Any suggestions on what user I should try, or better yet how to eliminate the need to enter credentials at all?

Answer (score 1):

Does your windows user have permissions for this site ?

Comment: Where do I go to verify this? Is it under the properties menu of the website in the IIS manager?

Comment: Well, it depends how permissions are organized in your CMS. I'm not very familiar with SiteFinity CMS, but check its documentation for how to setup user permissions. It's not a IIS manager property though.

Comment: What doesn't seem to make sense to me is it prompts for the username and password before anything loads. If I navigate to http://localhost/ without debugging anything, it still prompts me for a username and password.

Comment: That's correct. This is the way windows authentication works.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I'll check out the documentation and see what I can do from there. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest, first use forms authentication to be able to login in the admin panel and the set proper permission for your windows accounts.